Issue with AWS Polly Integration in .net: AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service
I'm integrating AWS Polly (TTS) into my Unity game and wrote the following code:
public AwsPollyAPIClient(AwsPollyCredentials pollyCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint)
{
    this._pollyCredentials = pollyCredentials;
    this._regionEndpoint = regionEndpoint;
    var credentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(pollyCredentials.AccessKeyId, pollyCredentials.SecretAccessKey, pollyCredentials.SessionToken);

    var client = new Amazon.Polly.AmazonPollyClient(credentials, _regionEndpoint);
}

I am confident that the session-based AWS credentials are correct because they work when tested with Postman (screenshot below):

However, when I run this code, I encounter an AmazonServiceException with the following error message:
AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials () (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials () (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync () (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at <079bbcd1e33a44ceb475e71d2b08b487>:0)
AwsPollyAPIClient.SynthesizeSpeech (System.String
...

Additional Information:
AWS SDK Code Version: 3.7.304.3
AWS SDK Polly Version: 3.7.303.6
The error message is: "AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service." What does this even mean? I've tested my session-based credentials via Postman, and they work fine. Does the AWS SDK assume something behind the scenes? Should I write custom code to sign the AWS request and call the AWS Polly API directly instead?
Please help!

Can you please share how you are creating this AwsPollyCredentials object?
